# Deployed project successfully, Heroku 503 error when trying to open in web

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, package.json

Was able to push my stack app to Heroku and have it deploy successfully with no error, but when opening the link it gives me a 503 error. I am curious to if I'm missing something in my package.json or my server is setup incorrectly. "heroku logs --tail" was able to show me the error, and the error below says im missing script start. I've checked my script in package.json but I am not missing the start script in my package.json and added the build script in my server package.json to build my React app. My full project is available here:

https://github.com/Pillbug23/caltrails.github.io

```
2022-02-02T06:07:23.227967+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
2022-02-02T06:07:23.228160+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-02-02T06:07:23.228451+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
2022-02-02T06:07:23.228682+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
2022-02-02T06:07:23.228922+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
2022-02-02T06:07:23.229031+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-02-02T06:07:23.229122+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
2022-02-02T06:07:23.229220+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   npm run
2022-02-02T06:07:23.241797+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-02T06:07:23.242242+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-02-02T06:07:23.242362+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-02-02T06_07_23_230Z-debug.log
2022-02-02T06:07:23.394883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json file is missing the node js version declaration. Heroku would require it when building to target that specific version.

```json
"engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
```

See this link for more info.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node